# How do I record my microphone in either mono or in both channels

Tags: macos, audio, soundflower, sound-volume

Right now I am using the MacOS's default screen recorder to record gameplay, soundflower for laptop audio output, and a Samson C01U as a microphone. I've setup an aggregate device with my mic, soundflower 2ch and my external headphones shown below:

[image: Audio Input]

My output is a multi-output device with my headphones and soundflower 2ch, show below:

[image: Audio Output]

However, when I finish recording, everything is fine however my microphone playback is only on the RIGHT side, and not the left. What could I do to achive the microphone audio playing back on both speakers?

Comment: Can I summarize this as your recording has only one channel and you need to change the mix in post so it’s split 50/50 stereo?

Comment: You need to sum it or split it [in effect make the Mac aware it is a mono source] before it reaches the Mac - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418240/how-do-i-troubleshoot-screen-capture-utilities-only-capturing-one-side-of-audio

Comment: @bmike Yes, thats correct